# Cannot boot windows after dual booting ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, ssd, bios

The grub screen shows the windows option but after selecting it, windows doesn't gets booted and again after some time grub screen appears.
But I am able to boot ubuntu.

Comment: Could you provide the `sudo os-prober` output inside your question?

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. So if Windows turns fast starup on, needs chkdsk or has other issues grub will not boot it. If UEFI, you should be able to directly boot from UEFI boot menu and see what the Windows issue is. If BIOS you have to temporarily install Windows BIOS boot loader to MBR, fix Windows & then reinstall grub. Best to always have both Windows repair flash drive & Ubuntu live installer to make repairs when needed.